# Azure SQL Database - How to change time zone settings?

Tags: azure, timezone

My Azure server is hosted in East US. In the SQL DB, when I use `getdate()`, it returns UTC time. But I need to get EST time. How can I achieve it? Is there any setting I need to change?

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/timezones-overview), Azure SQL Database does not support time zone settings; it always follows UTC . Use [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Database if you need to interpret date and time information in a non-UTC time zone.

Comment: That's right, Joseph Xu.

Comment: Hi @Iniyavan, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get the current time in the US Eastern time zone is:

```sql
select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
```

This returns a `datetimeoffset` and accounts correctly for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

OP has developed a function:

```
FN_GET_EST(GETDATE()). 

CREATE FUNCTION FN_GET_EST(@p_in_date as datetime) returns DATETIME 
as 
begin 
DECLARE @dt_offset AS datetimeoffset 
SET @dt_offset = CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @p_in_date) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' 
RETURN CONVERT(datetime, @dt_offset); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Xu. I have created a small function, ```FN_GET_EST``` to get the EST. Instead of ```GETDATE()```, I will use ```FN_GET_EST(GETDATE())```.

Comment: Don't use "US Eastern Standard Time" unless you specifically mean the Eastern part of Indiana.  Otherwise you won't have DST information for 2005 and earlier.  I edited your answer to remove "US".

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint Thank you sir.